# Garbled stash:nocache output when in stash:set_list in a nested embed

Tags: stash, embeds, caching, list

I'm putting together a sort of [ViewModel-ish](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Mvvm-%28model-view-viewmodel%29) setup and getting strange output from `{stash:nocache}`

Here's the setup. First, the EE template:

```
{stash:embed
  context="@URI"
  file_name="viewmodels:detail"
  parse_stage="both"
  stash:_type="blog"
  stash:_layout="standard"
 }
```

#### viewmodels/detail.html

```
{stash:embed:layouts:{stash:_layout} priority="1"}

{stash:embed 
  file_name="viewmodels:detail:{stash:_type}"}
```

#### viewmodels/detail/blog.html

```
{exp:channel:entries [single entry parameters...]}

[SNIP store some other data, eg title, body…]

  {exp:stash:set_list name="post_links" parse_conditionals="yes" parse_tags="yes"}
    [SNIP some other items…]

    {stash:link}
      {if forum_topic}
        {path='forums/viewthread'}/{forum_topic_id}/
      {if:else}
        {stash:nocache}
          {if logged_in}
            {path='/forums/newtopic/18/'}
          {if:else}
            /forums/member/login/
          {/if}
        {/stash:nocache}
      {/if}
    {/stash:link}
    {stash:text}
      {if forum_topic}
        Discuss in the forums
      {if:else}
        {stash:nocache}
        {if logged_out}Log in and start{if:else}Start{/if} a discussion in the forums
        {/stash:nocache}
      {/if}
    {/stash:text}

  {/exp:stash:set_list}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

#### layouts/standard.html

(part of it)

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="post_links"}
  <a href="{link}">{text}</a> <br/>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

All told, that outputs

```
<a href="[_Stash_1_SOMERANDOMLETTERSANDNUMBERS]">[_Stash_2_SOMERANDOMLETTERSANDNUMBERS]</a> <br/>
```

At first I thought it might an issue using `{stash:nocache}` within the `{stash:KEY}` elements of `{exp:stash:set_list}`, so I tried `prefix="CUSTOM"` on any/all of the `{stash:embed}`s and using `{CUSTOM:nocache}`, but that got me the same sort of garbled result. No combination of `parse_stage="both"` on any of the nested embeds seemed to make a difference either.

Extra weird, if I place the contents of `viewmodels/detail/blog.html` directly in 'viewmodels/detail.html' instead of the nested embed and just use `{stash:nocache}`, that works OK. So I could do that. But if anyone has any ideas why those list/`{stash:nocache}` elements are getting parsed that way so I could use the nested embed, that'd be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, looks like the issue was not having a distinct enough name for the stash list.  "videos" was changed to "related_videos" and this solved the issue